# Google ads in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ads

I want to integrate Google ads in my iPhone native app. So, can you please give us some procedures so that I can test with some demo testing (Not the paid one).

I checked out with this

[Grow revenue by selling ads on your mobile app](http://www.admob.com/home/reg_landing/)

Kindly help me to get this done.

regards,
Siddhesh.

Comment: What have *YOU* done to try to get this done?

Comment: Why dont you can look for iAD?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this

[Admob integrate in your iphone application](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-admob-integrate-in-your-application-in-iphone/)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean Google Adsense by that, this is not working. You aren't allowed to include google adsense ads in mobile native applications.
But even better would be the iAds by Apple, which are especially for iOS apps.